# Quiero saber con una consulta sql me muestre cual de todos los campos de una tabla es llave foranea

Tags: java, mysql, sql, python-3.x, html5

necesito una consulta sql que me muestra uno o todos los campos de una tabla que son llave foranea preferiblemente que funcione con mysql
ya intente con esto
 `SELECT *FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME  = 'NombreTabla'`
y no funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como puedes leer en la [documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-key-column-usage-table.html) de MySQL la tabla `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` describe que columnas tienen constraints

asi que podrias armar una consulta como la siguiente

```
SELECT column_name as "llave foranea", referenced_table_name "tabla donde se usa", referenced_column_name "nombre de la llave foranea en la tabla relacionada"
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE table_name = 'nombre_de_tu_tabla'
AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL;
```